# How do I remove certain lists from an existing list?

Tags: python, list, automation

I want to remove the lists which have 2 or fewer values from within another list.

For instance, below in my example x list, I don't want the first two lists to be included but, only keep the lists that have 3 or more values inside of them.

```
x=[[1.425003414959913], [1.4462819804110294, 1.313158773600076], [1.4346191329949716, 1.2678556765646085, 1.3947306585380852, 2.0080236552524413]
```

I am still new to python and automation so I appreciate any help!

Comment: Your question is inconsistent. You said you want to remove the lists with 2 or fewer values. Then you say you want to keep the lists that have more than 3 values. The first means to keep lists with exactly 3, the second means to remove lists with exactly 3. Which is it?

Comment: Can you be more specific about which part you're struggling with? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: But the logic is the same no matter what the specific number is.

Comment: Please repeat the intro tour.  Also see [help me](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use list comprehension:

```
x2 = [val for val in x if len(val) > 2]
```

this will create the list x2, which contains all elements of x (val) with a length larger then 2.